# Перенос проекта с одного ПК на другой

Tags: python, django, pipenv

На курсах python-разработчиков делал проект. Был один ноут с проектом, сам проект храню на Github. Проект недоделан, но разворачивается локально и на хероку.
Приобрел новый ноутбук установил все необходимое: PyCharm, развернул pipenv и т.д.

PyCharm предложил сделать Pipenv update - сделал.

Выполнил команду `pipenv install --dev`.

Пытаюсь запустить сервер: `pipenv run python manage.py runserver`, либо `python manage.py runserver`.

Получаю то, что изображено на скриншоте.
[image: Выпадающие исключения]

Ссылка на проект в Github: [Мой учебный проект](https://github.com/Stanlyzoolo/meduzer)

Текст исключений, мне показалось, намекает на отсутствие базы данных на новом ноуте?

Прошу подказать или направить на решение этой проблемы, потому что надо доделывать проект, он является "дипломным" на курсах, а я не могу приступить к коду.

Comment: Видимо DATABASE_URL где-то забыли прописать

Comment: DATABASE_URL у меня записан в конфиге в файле .secrets.yaml следующим образом:
`DATABASE_URL="postgresql://madpotato:123@localhost:5432/meduzer"`

И я тут не понимаю каким образом его надо поправлять